# Empty std::vector begin != end

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std

I am wondering if someone had experiance that having empty vector, but begin and end iteratos are not the same?

Thanks

Comment: Weird... do you have a code sample to justify the question?

Comment: Considering, that it is a strict requirement for `begin()` being equal to `end()` for an empty `std::vector` I doubt that anyone has observed this before. Unless we aren't talking about C++ or a compliant C++ implementation. In that case, what compiler and platform are you using?

Comment: I seem to recall having run into that, but it was probably at least 20 years ago (maybe more) when this whole "STL" thing was new and, and bugs were common.

Comment: Yes I know in general it must not be possible, but I have this on Windows 10. As the source code is closed, I cant copy past parts of it. I wrote here in ope that someone had such case and could give me some info what was problem, thanks anyway

Comment: I would rather close it not as duplicate, but for lack of MCVE. But closed of course.

Answer (score 3):

That should not be possible.  The standard states in [container.requirements.general]/6

> `begin()` returns an iterator referring to the first element in the container. `end()` returns an iterator which
>   is the past-the-end value for the container. If the container is empty, then `begin() == end();`

so if `contianer.empty() == true` then `container.begin()` must equal `container.end()`

Comment: I know what standart says, but please be more open minded and not take that as laws of nature. There can be such cases and I am just wandering if someone had such

Comment: I'm not not being open minded I am just stating the according to the standard it can't happen.  If it is then you have a bug in your implementation and it needs to be fixed.

Comment: @IrakliDarbuashvili: Those are the rules, and I don't know of a single current C++ implementation that fails to meet them. Since you think that providing and MCVE is somehow giving away secret information I'd be more inclined to believe, that you are not very experienced, and what you observe is a bug in your code, or misinterpretation of your observations.